# NSWorkspace launchApplicationAtURL not working with NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, launch, nsworkspace

The following works from Terminal:

```
open -a cyberduck ftp://anonymous@mirror.switch.ch/mirror
```

and opens the FTP site, indicating that it is processing its argument.

But the following code does not. Cyberduck opens OK, but ignores its argument:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:
  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Applications/Cyberduck.app"]
  options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
  configuration:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
  [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ftp://anonymous@mirror.switch.ch/mirror"]
  forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments]
  error:&error];
```

On return, error is nil.

This is on Lion. I can't use openFile:withApplication:, because the argument is not a file name. (I tried.)

This does work, and I'm inclined to use it:

```
system("open -a cyberduck ftp://anonymous@mirror.switch.ch/mirror");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. According to my understanding of the documentation this is the way that should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sending the workspace [an `openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURLs%3awithAppBundleIdentifier%3aoptions%3aadditionalEventParamDescriptor%3alaunchIdentifiers%3a).